# Magento 2 Multistore : Disable Customer sharing account between the stores of same website

Tags: magento2

I have one website with 3 stores. Is it possible that customers of one stores should not be able to loggin to other 2 stores.
The customer should not share cart between the stores. Is there an extension for this. Please advice.

Answer (score 0):

By default Magento has support for this function
You can access it at: Stores-> Customers-> Customer Configuration-> Account Sharing Options. In the field ""Share Customer Accounts"" select Per Website
https://prnt.sc/117xpom

Comment: Is there a extension for that ?

Comment: I'm afraid no. It is a default function of Magento